# How to create two clients if using RedisStore?

Tags: node.js, redis

I'm trying to implement redis pub/sub, and I want to use redis in order to store sessions.
How can I create two clients for one store ?
I found how to make one client for store:

```
app.use(express.session({
        secret: 'mysecret',
        store: new RedisStore({
            client:db,
            secret:config.db.auth
        })
    }));
```

But how can I make more than one ?

Comment: is it possible to create redis store and then use redis.createClient(port, host, options) on each client ?

Comment: Is it possible to pass redis.createClient to RedisStore like this https://gist.github.com/durango/4195802 ?